# Does $\int _0^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{1+x^2\left(\sin x\right)^2}\ \operatorname dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I have been trying to prove the following integral:

> $$\int _0^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{1+x^2\left(\sin x\right)^2}\ dx$$

diverges (please correct me if I am mistaken).

I have tried to use different comparison tests (as this is an integral of a positive function) with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to look at the link below. It's a different example but similar.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185515/improper-integral-int-0-infty-frac-rm-dx1x4-sin2x/2185713#2185713

Answer (score 5):

The integral would diverge if $x^2\sin^2(x)$ was "quite small" when $x$ is near a multiple of $\pi$. Using the periodicity of $\sin(x)$, we can examine the behavior near $k\pi$ by shifting and looking at
$$ (x+k\pi)^2 \sin^2(x) \approx (x+k\pi)^2 x^2$$
for $x$ near $0$. This is valid for very small $x$ through the Taylor polynomial, in a way that could be made rigorous.

For $\lvert x \rvert < \frac{1}{2k\pi}$ (for $k \geq 1$), we have that
$$(x+k\pi)^2 \sin^2(x) \leq 2.$$
So for $\lvert x \rvert < \frac{1}{2k\pi}$, we have
$$ \frac{1}{1+(x+k\pi)^2 \sin^2(x)} \geq \frac{1}{3}.$$

With this in mind, we can write
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x^2\sin^2(x)}dx &= \sum_{k \geq 0} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{1}{1 + x^2\sin^2(x)}dx  \\
&= \sum_{k \geq 0} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{1 + (x+k\pi)^2\sin^2(x)}dx.
\end{align}$$
Now as everything in sight is positive, 
$$ \begin{align}
\sum_{k \geq 0} \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{1 + (x+\pi)^2\sin^2(x)}dx &\geq \sum_{k \geq 1} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2\pi k}} \frac{1}{1 + (x+k\pi)^2\sin^2(x)}dx \\
&\geq \sum_{k \geq 1} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2\pi k}} \frac{1}{3} dx\\
&\geq \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{6\pi k}, 
\end{align}$$
which diverges.

In other words, I believe that $x^2\sin^2(x)$ is "quite small" when $x$ is near $k\pi$, and it is "quite small" in a region that decays linearly with $k$. And this is enough to show that the integral diverges.

Comment: I think the bit about $k$ large enough should be more clear. On one hand, we have $(x+k\pi)^2\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$. On the other, $\sin(x)^2\to0$ as $k\to\infty$. It's not immediately clear what happens to the product.

Comment: The only requirement for $k$ to be large is to make the implicit error in the approximation $\sin x \approx x$ to be accurate enough. In fact, for $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2\pi k}$, we actually have $\sin x < \frac{1}{2\pi k}$, so by "for $k$ large enough" I really mean "for $k \geq 1$".

Comment: I should add that this is not meant to cast doubt on the answer, because it *is* correct and my comment above isn't even about the main point (the last paragraph in the answer). This is a very good answer.

Comment: Thank you --- I will make an edit there, though. (And also correct something about having divided by $0$ in my original answer --- whoops!)

Answer (score 1):

We can agree that $1+x^2(\sin x)^2$ evaluates to 1 periodically right ?

Then you can define a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $  so that :

$$f(x) = 0 \text{ if } {1\over1+x^2\sin(x)^2}\le {1\over 2}$$
$$f(x) = {1\over 2} \text{  if } {1\over1+x^2\sin(x)^2}\gt {1\over 2}$$

Then it is easy to prove $$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$$ diverges.

And since we have by construction : $$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^+, 0\le f(x) \lt {1\over1+x^2\sin(x)^2} $$

Then you can conclude that $\int_0^\infty {1\over1+x^2\sin(x)^2}$ diverges too.

Comment: The thoughts behind our approaches are very similar. However, it may be that $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ (in your terminology) on increasingly small sets as $x$ increases, like within sets of width $1/k^2$ near $x=k\pi$. In this case, $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$ converges just fine. So there is more to be said than what's included in this answer.

Comment: That function is not periodic.

Comment: mixedmath you're absolutely right I missed the point on this. I understood it once I read your answer. Mea culpa =)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to bound the integral below on intervals where $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+x^2\left(\sin x\right)^2}$ has spikes, that is to say, it suffices to find some $\varepsilon_k$ such that $$\sum_{k\geq1}\int_{k\pi -\varepsilon_k}^{k\pi +\varepsilon_k}\frac{1}{1+x^2\left(\sin x\right)^2}dx$$ diverges.

On each of these intervals, since $\sin^2(x)$ is $\pi$-periodic, $1+x^2\sin^2(x)\leq 1+(k\pi + \varepsilon_k)^2\sin^2(\varepsilon_k)$, hence $$\sum_{k=1}^N\int_{k\pi -\varepsilon_k}^{k\pi +\varepsilon_k}\frac{1}{1+x^2\left(\sin x\right)^2}dx \geq \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{2 \varepsilon_k}{1+(k\pi + \varepsilon_k)^2\sin^2(\varepsilon_k)}$$

Some rough asymptotics suggest $$\frac{2 \varepsilon_k}{1+(k\pi + \varepsilon_k)^2\sin^2(\varepsilon_k)}\sim \frac{2 \varepsilon_k}{\pi^2k^2\epsilon^2_k}=\frac 2\pi \frac{1}{k^2\varepsilon_k} $$

Setting $\varepsilon_k=\frac 1k$ seems therefore like a sound idea, since we would get something like the harmonic series, which diverges.

Indeed, $$\begin{align}\frac{ \frac 2k}{1+(k\pi + \frac 1k)^2\sin^2(\frac 1k)}&=\frac 2k \frac{1}{1+(\pi^2k^2+2\pi +\frac{1}{k^2})(\frac{1}{k^2}+o(\frac{1}{k^2}))} \\
&=\frac 2k \frac{1}{1+\pi^2 + o(1)}\\
&\sim \frac{2}{1+\pi^2}\frac{1}k
\end{align}$$

With this choice of $\varepsilon_k$, $\displaystyle \sum_{k\geq 1}^\infty \frac{2 \varepsilon_k}{1+(k\pi + \varepsilon_k)^2\sin^2(\varepsilon_k)}$ diverges, which concludes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The integrand features a series of peaks of unit height around $k\pi$. If we can show that the width of the peaks decreases slowly, we are done.

We have

$$\frac1{1+x^2\sin^2x}\ge\frac12$$ when

$$|x\sin x|\le1$$ or, with $x=k\pi+t$ and $|t|<\pi$,

$$|(k\pi+t)\sin t|\le|(k\pi+t)t|\le1.$$

The condition is fulfilled with $$|t|\le\frac1{4k}$$
so that the total area diverges (the area of a peak is a least $\dfrac12$ times the width).

[image]